# iPad resize UIView when keyboard is shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, ios7

I am running a phonegap application on iOS7 and I need to resize the UIView when the keyboard opens and when the orientation of the device changes.

I have some of the resize working but I am stuck when the orientation of the device is LandscapeRight, the first time the keyboard opens it slides up then the second time it slides it up even more.

I have search similar answers on stackoverflow and none have solved what I am looking for. So, please don't just copy and paste a solution from else where, thanks.

MainViewController.m

```
int screenWidth;

int screenHeight;

float keyboard_offset = 80.0;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDidHide:) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];

        CGRect viewBounds = [self.webView bounds];
        viewBounds.origin.y = 20;
        viewBounds.size.height = viewBounds.size.height - 20;
        self.webView.frame = viewBounds;

        self.webView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        self.webView.opaque=NO;
        screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
        screenHeight = self.view.frame.size.height;
    }

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)orientationChange:(NSNotification *)note
{
    UIDevice * device = note.object;

    switch(device.orientation)
    {
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            [self.view setFrame: CGRectMake(-keyboard_offset, 0, screenWidth + keyboard_offset, screenHeight)];
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            [self.view setFrame: CGRectMake(keyboard_offset, 0, screenWidth + keyboard_offset, screenHeight)];
            break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            [self.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    };
}

- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChange:)
                                          name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                          object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];

    if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        [self.view setFrame: CGRectMake(-keyboard_offset, 0, screenWidth + keyboard_offset, screenHeight)];
    }
    else if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        [self.view setFrame: CGRectMake(keyboard_offset, 0, screenWidth + keyboard_offset,  screenHeight)];
    }
    else
    {
        [self.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardDidHide:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    [self.view setFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight)];
}
```

AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{   
    /*
     Orientation change for iOS7
    */
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7)
    {

        [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
                                                name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                                   object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];

        self.window.clipsToBounds = YES;
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyleBlackOpaque];
    }

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

/**
 * Change the status bar color on orientation change.
 */
- (void) orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)note
{
    UIDevice * device = note.object;
    switch(device.orientation)
    {
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
            self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(-20, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
            self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(-20, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight:
            self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(20, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
            self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(20, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortrait:
            self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 20, screenWidth, screenHeight);
            self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 20, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        break;
        case UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
            self.window.frame =  CGRectMake(0, -20, screenWidth, screenHeight);
            self.window.bounds = CGRectMake(0, -20, screenWidth, screenHeight);
        break;
        default:
        break;
    };
}
```

CDVViewController.m

```
/*
 Change the status bar color to the old style
 */
-(UIStatusBarStyle)preferredStatusBarStyle {
    return UIStatusBarStyleLightContent;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    /*
     Only perform these actions for iOS 7 or above
     */
    if([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7) {
        [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
    }
}
```

Comment: possible to attach a screenshot?

Comment: and the third time it goes even more up than the second time right?

Comment: @eli.d The first time it works as expected, then the second and so on goes up farther but not more for each time the keyboard is open (if that makes sense)